# Seamless Voroni Mesh with Displacement?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, displacement

*I'm trying to convert a plane with a voronoi displacement to a mesh and still have it tile correctly.* I use blender to make ceramic molds so I need the edges to line up when I bend it 360 into a cylinder. The voronoi *clearly tiles* since you can scale it up and down so it seems like this should be possible with the right settings.

[image]

Comment: The simplest way would be to use a 3D Voronoi in an object's space.. no seams, no repeats. I've made a 2D tileable Voronoi using GN, but not including distance-to-edge. Is that of any interest?